# How do I set up Qjackctl without using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, sound, pulseaudio, midi, automatic

I can now open Qjackctl using the terminal. This is the code that I am using.

```
pulseaudio --kill
jack_control  start
```

This will open the program successfully. Then when I am finished I can type this code:

```
jack_control exit
pulseaudio --start
```

It takes a little bit of typing, but it works. How do I save the commands and make it work automatically? Thanks in advance for all of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a .desktop file for doing this.

First, create a script using terminal:

```
mkdir -p bin
gedit ~/bin/jack_control.sh
```

In the new opened file, add the following lines:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

pid=$(pgrep -x jack_control)

if [ "$pid" = "" ]; then 
    pulseaudio --kill
    jack_control  start
else
    jack_control exit
    pulseaudio --start
fi
```

Save the file, close it and make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/jack_control.sh
```

Now you can create your .desktop file:

```
gedit ~/Desktop/jack_control.desktop
```

In the new opened file, add the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Qjackctl
Comment=Start or stop jack_control
Exec=/home/your_username/bin/jack_control.sh
Icon=/path/to/icon.png    # <-- this line is optional
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Save the file, close it and make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/jack_control.desktop
```

Finally, go to desktop and test your new .desktop file.

More about: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: Hello, I really appreciate your help. I did what you said but got this error message- Could not find the home/brian/-Desktop/~jack_control.esktop. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again. On the line Icon-/path/to/icon.png, are there three spaces between that and # <-- or two? Also, the the words this line is optional, is the for me or part of the text?

Comment: @BJsgoodlife Be careful with the paths. `home/brian/-Desktop/~jack_control.esktop` it's wrong at all. In desktop file use: `Exec=/home/brian/bin/jack_control.sh`. That line `Icon=/path/to/icon.png    # <-- this line is optional` as says is optional. This is a comment: `# <-- this line is optional`, so delete it. If you want to assign an icon to your desktop file, then change `/path/to/icon.png` with the path to the icon; if you don't want, delete that line.

Comment: Ok I got it to work but then it stopped working again. I have done it a number of times, so maybe what I need to do is delete all the files and start over. How do you do that?

Comment: @BJsgoodlife There are only 2 files: `~/bin/jack_control.sh` and `~/Desktop/jack_control.desktop`; `~` stands for `/home/brian` (in your case) - these are equivalent.

Comment: Radeanu, ok how do you delete them? I tried to do it by typing sudo apt-get remove but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @BJsgoodlife Just use [Nautilus](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/nautilus/) - the default file manager in Ubuntu.

Comment: Radeanu, just to clarify on the icon would that be Icon=/jack_control/path/to/icon.png?

Comment: @BJsgoodlife Are you so noob? You can get some basic help [here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=application+icons+ubuntu) and [here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ubuntu+show+file+path)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this to be as fast and simple to use as possible - this script will work great in tandem with a quick access terminal like Yakuake or Guake:

```
#!/bin/bash

####################################################
#
# Use this CLI util to toggle pulse audio <--> jackd
#
# This program will start by shutting down the
# pulseaudio systems and starting up a jack daemon.
# It'll then wait for you to press any key. When you
# do, it'll close the jack daemon and restart pulse.
#
####################################################

function write() {
  echo -e "\033[036m`basename $0:`#\033[0m $1"
}

pulseaudio --kill
jack_control start

write 'press any key to toggle back to pulseaudio..'
read

jack_control exit
pulseaudio --start
```

Save this to a file named `qjack` (or whatever) that's in your `$PATH`, `chmod 755 qjack` to make it executable.